# strip xml attribute id's using C# .NET 4

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm passing some xml to a server and when doing a POST I need to strip the attribute id's, but I'm not sure how to do that using c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\mydoc.xml")
myDoc.Descendants("myNode").Attributes("id").Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET's [XML Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to load an XML document and then you could simply just cycle through all the element and remove any attributes that are ID's and save the result...

... I suppose you also could use a regular expression to remove it from a string though.